# For loop inside a formula in crystal reports

Tags: for-loop, crystal-reports

Say I want to find the ten most common things in a list. Crystal reports allows you to do this easily one by one with the Nthmostfrequent function. I am curious if we can do this a bit more efficiently say using a for loop..

I tried

```
local numbervar i;
local stringvar result;
local stringvar result = nthmostfrequent(i,{ticket.diagnosis});
for i :=1 to 10 do
(
    nthmostfrequent(i,{ticket.diagnosis});
    i := i+1;
);
result;
```

But it doesn't work saying a number is expected at i in the formula.

Edit: thinking I also need to initialize an array to house the results?
Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula has a few issues. Most notably:

1. On line 3 you're attempting to use `i` before it is initialized.
2. The call to `NthMostFrequent()` isn't having its results saved anywhere. You're right in that you'll need to use an array to save your values.

Try this instead

```
local numbervar i;
local stringvar array result;
redim result [10];

for i :=1 to 10 do
    (
      result[i]:=nthmostfrequent(i,{ticket.diagnosis})
    );

//A formula cannot evaluate to an array. This collapses the array into a string
join(result, ', ')
```

EDIT: It appears that `NthMostFrequent()` will NOT accept a variable for its first parameter value; it must be passed an explicit integer. This method won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am still getting the same error saying that "a number is expected here" and then the cursor goes to the i in nthmostfrequent. I am using an outdated version of crystal reports so maybe that is the problem?

Comment: @BrinnRiordan Nope, you're right. Crystal won't let me use a variable as the first parameter either. The help file explicitly says "integer" and I think they're drawing a distinction between numerical types. Sorry, I don't think this will work after all.

Comment: Darn this inflexibility! Thanks again for your help!